# Как вывести в массив названия столбцов со значениями в заданной строке больше заданной?

Tags: python, pandas

Как вывести в массив названия столбцов где значения в заданной строке больше одного? Например, в первой строке:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
0   0   1   3   0   1   2   0   0
4   2   1   2   1   1   0   1   0
```

Чтобы получилось:

```
['D', 'G']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

получаем список столбцов, для которых в 0-й строке значения больше `1`:

```
In [64]: df.columns[df.gt(1).loc[0]].to_list()
Out[64]: ['D', 'G']
```

получаем список столбцов, для которых в 1-й строке значения больше `1`:

```
In [65]: df.columns[df.gt(1).loc[1]].to_list()
Out[65]: ['A', 'B', 'D']
```